# IntelliJ Nashorn debugging and evaluating JO objects gives error

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, nashorn

When debugging some JavaScript that is running in the Nashorn interpreter (running in version 2016.3.4), I can see some of the variables are displayed properly as JavaScript objects and can be evaluated in the Evaluate Expression window, while others are displayed as JO objects. The ones that are displayed as JO objects cannot be evaluated as that gives a NativeReferenceError exception.

What can I do to see the JO objects as JavaScript variables and evaluate them?

[IntelliJ window showing how some JavaScript objects cannot be evaluated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDW0d.png)

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be remarkably easy to work around. It was just necessary to capture the JavaScript variables within a Java class so they could be referenced in the Evaluate Expression window. A class like this would do the job:

```
package foo;

import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror;

public class NashornCapture {
    private static Object[] args;
    private static ScriptObjectMirror arg;

    public static void capture(Object... vars) {
        args = vars;
    }

    public static void capture(ScriptObjectMirror vars) {
        arg = vars;
    }

    public static Object arg(int index) {
        return args[index];
    }

    public static Object arg(String name) {
        return arg.get(name);
    }
}
```

and then you can reference the variables by index or name, as the following image shows.

[IntelliJ window showing how you can evaluate variables using a helper class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4FK2.png)